# Termux API does not ask for permissions and hangs

Tags: permissions, termux

I try to use termux-api to perform some actions, specifically I want to use termux-usb to run some libuvc code.

However none of termux api programs even ask for permissions to run.

For example if I run

```
termux-camera-photo test.jpeg
```

It just hangs, same for `termux-usb -l`

It is Samsung Galaxy A31, Android 10.

Comment: According to [the Wiki for `termux-usb`](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-usb), it needs `-r` to show permission dialog when needed. As for `termux-camera-photo`, perhaps [there's no camera ID 0](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-camera-photo)?

Comment: Same behavoir with `-r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to install Termux-API via f-droid rather that pkg install - and thus it gets the permissions and pops the question.

if you install termux-api via command line tool `pkg install termux-api` - it fails.

If you install it as an app from f-droid - you can give permissions for example to use camera as to regular app, and `termux-usb` actually pops-up the question to use the device and thus giving permissions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).